# Arch linux won't start in default mode

Tags: linux

I get error everytime when I'm starting system. It says `[FAILED] Failed to mount /run/user/1000/gvfs`

I typed `systemctl status run-user-1000-gvfs.mount` 
Active:  failed (result: exit-code)

Answer (score 1):

For me worked generating new fstab file 
`rm /etc/fstab`
`genfstab -P -U / >> /etc/fstab`